# Trying to parse network flows to extract files in C using libpcap. I want to maintain a hashtable with a flow id for each flow.

Tags: c, networking, tcp, hashtable

What should be my key for the hashtable? And what should be the value? My idea is a hash using the 5 tuple information from the flow will be the key and the value will be the flow data structure itself. Is this line of thinking right?